# Scaling objects with data modification

Tags: python, armature

I am fairly new to blender and am wondering how does one scale the objects in blender via python script.

Currently I am simply changing the scale of the object via bpy.data.objects[NAME].scale
however, this is not what I want to do as it only visually shrink the object.

I also tried to change the length of each bone individually, however, even though the length of the bone changed, the head and tail of the bone did not change. Also something worth mentioning, I am working with a hand. This ended up giving me a hand with tiny bones but not connected due to the bone's head remaining the same.

I would like the bones in the armature object to actually shrink/grow as well, since I am exporting this object later as BVH and would like to preserve the scaling.

Thanks

Comment: how are "the bones in the object" ? is the object an armature or a mesh parented to an armature ?

Comment: its just an armature, no mesh involved.

Comment: loop through bones and scale one by one

Comment: i know how to loop through the bones, but to scale the bone, what do you call? bpy.ops.transform.resize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is simple script for scaling all bones in the active armature :

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')

for bone in ob.pose.bones:    
     if not bone.parent : # since children inherit scale no need to scale them 
        bone.scale *=0.5

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

to remove scale inheritence  :

```
for bone in ob.data.bones:
        if bone.parent :
            bone.use_inherit_scale = False

#scale all bones
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
for bone in ob.pose.bones:    
        bone.scale *=0.5
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

scaling in edit mode :

```
import mathutils
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

mat = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(0.5, 3)

for bone in ob.data.edit_bones:
        bone.transform(mat,  scale = True, roll = False)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: This changes the hand visually, but when i get an individual bone's  length it's still the same as before without the scale. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: the children bones are in the local space of there parent , so if the parent is scaled by half the world of the child is scaled by half , it's length is the same but visually it's half what it was

Comment: if you want you can disable Inherit_scale in the bone tab and remove `if not bone.parent` to get what you want

Comment: with this script, if I were to export the object as BVH is the scaling preserved?

Comment: sorry i have no experience with BVH exporting : (  , you can try the second method and export a simple armature

Comment: when u said disable inherit_scale in the bone tab, how does one do this in python. I am currently doing everything via python, so i cant really touch any of the UI

Comment: @jim is the scale preserved after exporting ?

Comment: one thing to note though, after scaling with the script above, if I were to enter edit mode, the hand's size is back to original.

Comment: yes that's normal , also you should know blender provide separate access to edit bones and pose bones ( hence the use of `mode_set('pose')` ) , edit mode is the rest position the the pose mode will aplly its transformation on to generate the pose

Comment: oh, no wonder. But shouldnt I be manipulating the edit bones instead of pose bones? sorry for sounding dumb...

Comment: I assumed this was for animation !

Comment: It has animation, so If i were to just change the edit bones, the scaling should still be preserved even during animation no? Also if I simply change the length of each bone as you have done in your answer, the head and tail of the bone doesnt change, so what i have is a hand with tiny bones that arent connected

Comment: yes bones through all the animation will be scaled

Comment: OK will change to use an operator instead

Comment: I appreciate your patience with my stupidity very much. Thank you

Comment: @jim you are welcome : ) , try the update and see if it works

Comment: Yup, thank you very much for the help. I was actually looking at the transform() function for the bones earlier. But when i was testing it, it kept on giving me bad matrix error. Glad to see how it actually works. :) Sorry i cant upvote the answer, not enough rep yet :/

Comment: glad i cold help

Answer (score 0):

For BVH export using the Python API, there is a `global_scale` parameter that you can apply with some scaling factor to the export function. See [API doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_anim.html).